# Tomcat : NIOConnector throws exception

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, asynchronous, nonblocking

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I am using Cometd for chat. For this, it is necessary for me to use async-mode in tomcat. After some research I found out that I can configure tomcats NIO connector for async mode.

Even after doing that, I am getting the same error. I am posting my debug log, web.xml, and the server config. Kindly let me know what is wrong.

Debug Log :

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [cometd] in context with path [] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A filter or servlet of the current chain does not support asynchronous operations.
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.startAsync(Request.java:1658)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.startAsync(RequestFacade.java:1029)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.startAsync(ServletRequestWrapper.java:379)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.startAsync(ServletRequestWrapper.java:379)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$Servlet3SaveToSessionRequestWrapper.startAsync(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:246)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.startAsync(ServletRequestWrapper.java:379)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.HttpServlet3RequestFactory$Servlet3SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.startAsync(HttpServlet3RequestFactory.java:173)
    at org.cometd.server.transport.AbstractStreamHttpTransport.suspend(AbstractStreamHttpTransport.java:89)
    at org.cometd.server.transport.AbstractHttpTransport.processMetaConnect(AbstractHttpTransport.java:272)
    at org.cometd.server.transport.AbstractHttpTransport.processMessages(AbstractHttpTransport.java:194)
    at org.cometd.server.transport.AbstractStreamHttpTransport.process(AbstractStreamHttpTransport.java:73)
    at org.cometd.server.transport.AbstractStreamHttpTransport.handle(AbstractStreamHttpTransport.java:52)
    at org.cometd.server.CometDServlet.service(CometDServlet.java:102)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1695)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Server.xml : (I removed redirection on 8080 temporarily)

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" maxThreads="1000" port="8080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"/>

 <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" 
               scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false"  sslProtocol="TLS" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" connectionTimeout="20000"
               keystoreFile="/home/username/.keystore" keystorePass="password" />
```

Web.xml : (Cometd relevant part)

```
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>cometd</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.cometd.server.CometDServlet</servlet-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cometd</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/cometd/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

What is the problem, kindly let me know. I also tried adding in POM.xml the apache.tomcat.util with scope as provided, but that didn't help. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: If there is any more information necessary, kindly let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a session manager (Redis, Terracota...) ?
If yes you must have defined a session Valve in the context.xml file of your Tomcat.

```
<Valve className="com.orangefunction.tomcat.redissessions.RedisSessionHandlerValve" />
```

Try adding the asyncSupported="true" attribute to this config:

```
<Valve asyncSupported="true" className="com.orangefunction.tomcat.redissessions.RedisSessionHandlerValve" />
```